# How does one derive the trigonometric parametric equations for a circle w/o trigonometry?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This question seems simple to me, but I can't figure it out.

I *know* the parameterizations for a circle probably better than I know the back of my hand. I know why, geometrically, it works. I can visualize details of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ ratios.

... But how do they come about? That is, without already *knowing* what these parameterizations are and how they work, if I were to say: $$\text{Find me the parameterization of the shape given by the equation}\\x^2 + y^2 = 1$$ How would one go about doing it?

My first thought is:

Let $x = t$ so $y = \pm\sqrt{1-t^2}$ where $t \in [0,1]$; but how does one go from this to trigonometry? Is there a $\sin$ and $\cos$ definition that I'm missing out on?

Comment: Also keep in mind the identity $$\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$$

Comment: Once you know $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ then it's pretty clear isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what I'm looking for. Assume we *don't* know that identity. Is there a direct derivation outside of "Oh. I know $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, and I **also** know that $\cos^2 + \sin^2 = 1$."

Comment: See [Wikipedia: unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)

Answer (score 1):

A way to avoid the definition of $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ as the coordinates of a points on circle of radius $1$ is via the exponential function of a imaginary numbers, i.e. the Euler formula.

Using the definition of exponential we have:
$$
e^{ib}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(ib)^k}{k!}=1+ib+\dfrac{(ib)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{(ib)^3}{3!}+\cdots+\dfrac{(ib)^n}{n!}+\cdots=
$$
$$
=1-\dfrac{(b)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{(b)^4}{4!}-\dfrac{(b)^6}{6!}+ \cdots +i\left[ b-\dfrac{(b)^3}{3!}+\dfrac{(b)^5}{5!}+\cdots  \right]
$$
so, definig:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k\,x^{2k}}{(2k)!}=  1-\dfrac{(x)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{(x)^4}{4!}-\dfrac{(x)^6}{6!}+ \cdots = \cos(x)
$$
and
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k\,x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}= x-\dfrac{(x)^3}{3!}+\dfrac{(x)^5}{5!}+\cdots =\sin(x)
$$
we have 
$$
e^{i\theta}= \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)
$$
now we see that $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=|e^{i\theta}|=1$ and we find the isomorphism with the points on the circle.